# How to add "radio" buttons as rowFormatter in Tabulator table?

Tags: html, radio-button, tabulator

```
{
title:"#", formatter:"rowSelection", titleFormatter: "", hozAlign:"center", headerSort:false, width:60, minWidth:60, frozen: true
}
```

Nothing Worked. Can anyone suggest a way out ?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to add them as a row formatter, you would want to use an editor or a formatter on a specific cell.

Formatters are used for visual only information, You can find information on how to build a custom formatter in the docs https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/format#format-custom

Editors are used for users to edit data on the table, You can find information on how to build a custom editor in the docs https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/edit#edit-custom